# Can I make a line melee attack using melee multitargeting rule?

Tags: attack, open-legend

I intend to make a cool move by making attacks on enemies standing nearby each other by charging through them while attacking them.

The melee multitargeting rule is:

> **Melee Multi-targeting**
>   You may target any number of foes that are within your reach. When targeting more than one foe, you suffer disadvantage equal to the number of foes targeted (2 targets = disadvantage 2, 3 targets = disadvantage 3, etc.)

**Is it allowed to move between each attacks?** If not, this is only useful if you are attacked by more than one enemies.

Answer (score 2):

### Multiattack and multitarget are different

You are confusing [multiattack](https://openlegendrpg.com/feats/multi-attack_specialist) with [multitarget](https://openlegendrpg.com/core-rules/07-combat).

Multitarget is single attack roll against multiple targets. Multiattack is multiple attack against one or more targets.

By default, when you opt to multitarget using a single melee attack, all the targets must be in melee range, so you cannot do this using melee multitarget if all targets are not in melee range when you attack.

### How can you do this?

1. Legal way: multiattack. You must take at least one Multi Attack Specialist feat to do this.

   > At the start of your turn, you may declare that you are multi-attacking. You must state how many extra attacks you would like to make. You receive a corresponding number of additional major actions, which can only be used for attacks. All of your attacks this round suffer disadvantage equal to 3 times the number of additional attacks you declare (i.e., if you make 2 attacks, you suffer disadvantage 3; 3 attacks suffers disadvantage 6).

   The disadvantage with this approach is your attack will have a lot of disadvantage, and at low level you can only attack 2 targets.
2. Ask your DM: line area attack. The problem is:

   > Area attacks are only possible when you are using an extraordinary attribute, unless a specific weapon property or other rule allows you to make area attacks without an extraordinary attribute.

   You could flavor your attack as one single charging strike with a katana, for example, so you only roll for single area attack and move to the end of the line.
3. Ask your DM: melee multitarget. The problem is already stated above, but if you could convince your DM that the flavor makes sense for a melee multitarget, they might allow you to do this.
4. Ask your DM: melee multitarget with focus action charging. This might be able to convince your DM more than 3rd option, because you are forfeiting your move and minor actions too to accomplish this (you can't resist banes or sustain boon). Pitch that the name of the focus action is already "charging" and it has inherent disadvantage 1.

Comment: would be improved by adding links.